# Azure Service Bus: Read messages with offset

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm reading messages from Azure Service Bus in my C# application. I'm reading them from Dead Letter Queue but I suppose it doesn't matter here. I need to read a block of messages of a given size, starting at a given offset (aka a page of messages).

I came up with the following, very inefficient, code:

```
SubscriptionClient client  = SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString(
  connectionString, 
  topic, 
  QueueClient.FormatDeadLetterPath(subscription));

var result = new List<string>();
for (var i = 0; i < offset + size; i++)
{
  var msg = await client.PeekAsync();
  if (msg == null)
  {
    return result;
  }

  if (i >= offset)
  {
    result.Add(msg);
  }
}

return result;
```

Is there a way I can write this "seek" in a more efficient way?

Comment: There's no concept of offset. It's a queue, you can receive or peek. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-overview

Answer (score 0):

The [SubscriptionClient.ReceiveAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.subscriptionclient.receiveasync?view=azure-dotnet) method accepts an `Int64` sequence number (offset):

```
for (var i = offset; i < offset + size; i++)
{
    var msg = await client.ReceiveAsync(i);
    result.Add(msg);
}
```

Comment: Is the sequence number supposed to increase by 1 per message? Unfortunatelly the `PeekAsync` with sequence number seems to be returning the same message although offset is increasing.

Comment: The `offset` is not increasing. `i` is.

Comment: That's what I meant. I updated the code to reflect your diff and it returns the first message `size` times.

Comment: What SequenceNumber does the first returned message have?

Comment: It's 18577348462903296.